# Macro function with string of fprintf

Tags: c, macros, printf

This code snippet:

```
#define ERROR_MSG_DETAIL(msg_str) \
   fprintf(stderr, (msg_str) "%s\n, at # %d, file: %s\n", strerror(errno), __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

I wish I just input the error message

```
ERROR_MSG_DETAIL("my errors")
```

Macro should be expend to

```
fprintf(stderr, "my errors" "%s\n, at # %d, file: %s\n", strerror(errno), __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

The result should look like:

```
my errors
at # 15, file: t.c
```

but I got this error message when compile

```
 error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
   11 |  fprintf(stderr, (msg_str) "%s\n, at # %d, file: %s\n", strerror(errno), __LINE__, __FILE__)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach could have been to define the macro like this:

```
#define ERROR_MSG_DETAIL(msg_str) \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n, at # %d, file: %s\n", (msg_str), strerror(errno), __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

Your approach (even if it was syntactically correct) would have resulted in undefined behaviour if the string denominated by `msg_str` contained a `%` character, which means
`fprintf` would attempt to interpret that character. The approach above will work for every string, independent of the contained characters. As an aside, `msg_str` doesn't have to be a string literal; this approach will also work if the `msg_str` is a pointer to `char`, provided that it points to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can only concatenate string literals if there is no parentheses between them, so you should change your macro removing parentheses around `msg_str`:

```c
#define ERROR_MSG_DETAIL(msg_str) \
   fprintf(stderr, msg_str ": %s\n, at # %d, file: %s\n", strerror(errno), __LINE__, __FILE__)
```